# MTP extremely and prohibitively slow, appears hung

Tags: windows-7, android, mtp

I am connecting my Samsung Galaxy SIII LTE to my computer. I have not had this problem before, although MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) is generally slower compared to mass storage, it was still usable.

Today I find MTP to be prohibitively slow. Sometimes it could stay there "loading" for several minutes, even an hour, never completing. *This also happens with PTP.*

In this screenshot, the folder is supposed to have 14 files. When I opened it, it showed the first file. It took several minutes to show the second one. The folder is still "loading" (the pulsating green bar) as I type and a third file is yet to appear.

**Edit:** For some reason, a boot disk icon (with Windows logo) with the name "Local Disk" appeared as a third file! I can confirm there is no such actual file in the system and this is just some weird bug.

[image: The folder is stuck at "loading" forever]

I have tried the following:

- Restart the phone, twice.
- Change to PTP, change back to MTP.
- Restart the computer.
- Install [drivers from Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-I747MBBATT).
- Unplug and plug back in several times.

What could be the problem, and how do I resolve this?

If it is relevant, my phone is rooted but using stock ROM (Android 4.3).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you unplug your device, uninstall the Samsung drivers and uninstall your device right from the **Device Manager**, reboot your machine and then connect your phone again so windows installs the drivers again (make shure you have the option to download drivers from Windows Update enabled) and see if it works (MTP is a propietary protocol made by Microsoft, so I'd trust their drivers more than Samsung's, they work for me pretty well).

If that doesn't work try connecting your device through PTP and removing any suspicious files (.lnk's and .exe's), you may have to disable "Hide file extensions for known file types" from the folder options and run a check with `adwcleaner` is freeware and portable (that's for the suspicious windows icon you see, just in case).

Good luck.

Comment: I should have mentioned that PTP has the same problem. Also I can see in ES File Manager that there are no suspicious files. The boot disk icon is clearly a bug.

Comment: Also, it's [not a proprietary protocol](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/). It's used in proprietary DRM from Microsoft. Of course, that doesn't make it any less awful

Comment: @ADTC did you have any luck? I'm facing this issue as well (files appearing as "Local Disk" when connecting my phone with either MTP or PTP and accessing internal storage)